# How to use -WhatIf in the New-QADUser cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script and I want to find out the result of a New-QADUser command if the command fails.

I found an argument to the New-QADUser command called `-WhatIf` (which I believe to be run if the cmdlet call fails) but I can't find any good examples of using it, and my attempts to use it have failed.

Answer (score 2):

if a cmdlet fails it returns an error.  You can trap errors in powershell.  See [finding and avoiding errors](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/30/chapter-11-finding-and-avoiding-errors.aspx)

the -whatif parameter tells the cmdlet not to actually perform any actions but report of what the cmdlet would have done if allowed to.

Comment: It is possible to trap an Exception of a particular type.  But what type should I trap if I only want it to ignore Exceptions that occur when a user already exists?

Answer (score 1):

The `-whatif` parameter is pretty standard in PowerShell.  It will tell you (as best it can) what will happen if you execute the command that the `-whatif` parameter is appended to.  It must be run BEFORE you run the command or it's not useful.

Here's an example: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_whatif_confirm.htm#PowerShell_-whatIf_Example